# jQuery post() code - how to make cleaner and faster?

Tags: javascript, jquery, .post

I'm in the midst of learning how to code.

The code below shows what happens after I click a button - a jQuery `post()` call is made which submits the data to a PHP form and then displays the result from the database query into a div.

The code is fine, but I'm simply wondering if there's any way to make it better.

By better, I mean if there is any way to make the code more **readable**, **faster**, and **less buggy**.

```
$.post("load_product.php", {'ID': IDname}, function(json) {

        var product_details_array = $.parseJSON(json);

        var test_for_null = product_details_array[0];

        if ( test_for_null.length > 0)

        {

 $('#product_tags_container').append(
        "<div class='product_tags'>" + "<img id='remove_tag' src='../function icons/cross.png'>" + "<div id='product_texture_picture'>" + "<img src='" +  "product_pictures/" + product_details_array[4] + product_details_array[5] + "'>" + "</div>" + "<div id='product_title'>" + product_details_array[0] + "</div>" + "<br><br>" + "<div id='product_brand'>" + product_details_array[6] + "</div>" + "<div id='product_price'>"+  product_details_array[3] + "</div>" + "</div>");

         }
         });
```

Comment: Properly indent your code. What is buggy now? Faster how? Is "stop using jQuery" a valid suggestion to make it faster?

Comment: The code isn't buggy yet but I haven't tried it with heavy user loads so I wouldn't know. I'm just wondering if there's a better way of doing it than what I have done above. What's faster than jQuery?

Comment: "What's faster than jQuery?" Not using jQuery.

Comment: I just started so don't mind my ignorance. Is using plain Javascript faster than using a library? Or is there a faster library than jQuery out there?

Comment: Your append function is terrible (read: too long, unreadable, unmaintainable). That's why I love templates with bindings (e.g. Angularjs). Clean Js, so min as possible html in your js.

Comment: Yes. Using a library will always be slower than not using a library because of the overhead of said library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use this, but if I had to 'remake' this code, I'd do it like this:

```
$.post("load_product.php", {'ID': IDname}, function(json) {
    var product_details_array = $.parseJSON(json);
    if (product_details_array[0].length > 0) {
        $('#product_tags_container').append(
            "<div class='product_tags'>" + 
                "<img id='remove_tag' src='../function icons/cross.png'>" + 
                "<div id='product_texture_picture'>" +
                    "<img src='" + "product_pictures/" + product_details_array[4] + product_details_array[5] + "'>" + 
                "</div>" + 
                "<div id='product_title'>" + product_details_array[0] + "</div>" + 
                "<br><br>" + 
                "<div id='product_brand'>" + product_details_array[6] + "</div>" + 
                "<div id='product_price'>" + product_details_array[3] + "</div>" + 
            "</div>");
    }
});
```

In my opinion this is more readable. If I had to read your 1-line html code I'd re-format it to look like the example I gave first. If you or anyone else has to make an edit it would be easier to do like this.

EDIT:

```
function assembleProductHTML(product_details_array) {
    return "<div class='product_tags'>" +
                "<img id='remove_tag' src='../function icons/cross.png'>" +
                "<div id='product_texture_picture'>" +
                    "<img src='" + "product_pictures/" + product_details_array[4] + product_details_array[5] + "'>" +
                "</div>" +
                "<div id='product_title'>" + product_details_array[0] + "</div>" +
                "<br><br>" +
                "<div id='product_brand'>" + product_details_array[6] + "</div>" +
                "<div id='product_price'>" + product_details_array[3] + "</div>" +
            "</div>";
}

$.post("load_product.php", {'ID': IDname}, function(json) {
    var product_details_array = $.parseJSON(json);
    if (product_details_array[0].length > 0) {
        $('#product_tags_container').append(assembleProductHTML(product_details_array));
    }
});
```

Comment: That's a lot neater for sure. Thanks. However I'm also wondering if there's a better way to do it than append-ing a large chunk of divs like I have?

Comment: You could create a function which assembles the code and returns it. Look at my edit.

Comment: That's amazing. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I cleaned up all the unnecessary concatenation within your append function. The append function is too long to maintain in my opinion. I'm guessing your server side responses

No response: ''

JSON array is null: null

JSON array is empty: []

```
$.post("load_product.php", {
id: IDname
}).done(function(data) {
    if (data.length>0 && data!=null && data!='[]') {
        var product_details_array = $.parseJSON(data);
        $('#product_tags_container').append("<div class='product_tags'><img id='remove_tag' src='../function icons/cross.png'><div id='product_texture_picture'><img src='product_pictures/" + product_details_array[4] + product_details_array[5] + "'></div><div id='product_title'>" + product_details_array[0] + "</div><br><br><div id='product_brand'>" + product_details_array[6] + "</div><div id='product_price'>" + product_details_array[3] + "</div></div>");
    }
}
});
```